# Close popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a popup window which is opened using this code:

```
function _openpageview(fieldid,objectid,opennew)
{
var url='/s_viewpagefield.jsp?fieldid='+fieldid+'&codedid='+objectid;

  web_window = window.open(url,'_blank', 'menubar=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600,status=no,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,dependent=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');
   web_window.opener = window;
   web_window.focus();


}
```

How can I close that popup from within the popup?

```
window.close();
self.close();
web_window.close();
```

all did not work

Comment: the answer by @molokoloco worked great for me

Answer (score 43):

An old tip...

```
var daddy = window.self;
daddy.opener = window.self;
daddy.close();
```

Comment: Works so beautifully it almost made me cry *_*

Comment: Not working anymore in Safari (unless opened with `window.open`)

Comment: it is working fine

Answer (score 10):

You can only close a window using javascript that was opened using javascript, i.e. when the window was opened using :

```
window.open
```

then

```
window.close
```

will work. Or else not.

Answer (score 4):

For such a seemingly simple thing this can be a royal pain in the butt! I found a solution that works beautifully (class="video-close" is obviously particular to this button and optional)

```
 <a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();" class="video-close">Close this window</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your web_window variable must have gone out of scope when you tried to close the window. Add this line into your _openpageview function to test:

```
setTimeout(function(){web_window.close();},1000);
```

Comment: I need to call the close function from within the popup itself...will this work for that? As I understand it web_window would be local to the parent page and the popup wont be able to use this variable...

Comment: `self.close();` should do it.

Comment: That should work from within the popup. Did you check that the code is firing? Try using `alert("OK");self.close();` If you don't see the alert, your code isn't being run.

Answer (score 1):

in my case (joomla opened popup) I had to use this:

```
onclick="submit(); window.parent.location.reload(false);window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();"
```

Hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed to close my pop-up and redirect the user to his profile page when he clicks "ok" after reading some message
I tried with a few hacks, including setTimeout + self.close(), but with IE, this was closing the whole tab...

Solution :
I replaced my link with a simple submit button.

`<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='profile.html';">buttonText</button>`.
Nothing more.

This may sound stupid, but I didn't think to such a simple solution, since my pop-up did not have any form.

I hope it will help some front-end noobs like me !

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
<html>
<script>
var newWindow;

function openWindow() {
  newWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  newWindow.document.write('<a href="javascript:window.close();" class="video-close">Close this window</a>');
}

function closeWindow() {
  newWindow.close();
}
</script>
<h3 style="color:brown"> Close Window Example </h3>
<body>
<button onclick="openWindow()">Open New Window</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="closeWindow()">Close New Window </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Close a popup after print.**

In the parent windows

```
  let IframeLink = '../Sale/PriceKOT?SalesID=@(Model.SalesInfo.SalesID)&PrintTypeID=3';
     var newwindow = window.open(IframeLink, "KOT Print", 'width=560,height=550,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0');
    if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }

    function closeThisPopUp() {            
        newwindow.close();
        printf();
    }
```

In the child or popup window

```
 window.onafterprint = function (event) {
    opener.closeThisPopUp();
    window.close;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

using [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

> javascript:window.close()

Try This:

```
<html>
<header>
    <script>
        let newWebWindow;
        function openPageView() {
            newWebWindow = window.open("", "window", "width=200,height=100");
            newWebWindow.document.write(`<a href="javascript:window.close();"class="video-close">Close this window</a>`);
        }

        function closePageView() {
            newWebWindow.close();
        }
    </script>
</header>

<body>
    <h3 style="color:brown"> Close Window Example </h3>
    <button onclick="openPageView()">Open Page</button>
    <button onclick="closePageView()">Close Page</button>
</body>

</html>
```