# How to call a button click of another aspx page in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to call `Button.Click` of one `Page` from another `Page`, both pages are open. Second page is a  `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` popup from the first page.

When I click button in second page, the `ClientScript` popup should close and also it should fire `Button.Click` event in First Page.

Comment: You could abstract out the logic into something that can be used by both pages. A code example might help someone be more specific.

Comment: maybe you need to look into window.parent

Answer (score 2):

Not possible that easy. You can't call an event handler on another page's controls, and it sounds like a terrible design in my opinion.

I would suggest to move the contents of that event handler to another class, separate from the pages' code behind files and call it from the page you are in.

Other options could include javascript solutions, but you clearly statement you don't want to use those. Else, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125648/close-popup-window) could be a solution to close the window. For calling the event handler on 'page 1' you could do a postback.

Comment: @chetan: Need more help?