# Close popup after login when specified url is reached with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a button in my HTML code that opens a popup window to login to SharePoint. Afterwards I have to close the windows manually, because I don't use the SharePoint interface. Is there a way to close the popup after a certain url is reached, e.g. the sharepoint "dashboard" or homepage.

This is my code:

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popup','height=' + 600 + ',width=' + 600 + ',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes')
}
```

Comment: You can check the url with this window.location.href , Write an if condition to check the url and the hide the popup for that URL

Comment: you can call a closePopup with popupWindow.close(); function when that specific url is reached(check the previous url with current url)

Comment: So I just add an if statement to the same function?

Comment: call another function which will have closing popup trigger after url checks success @neolith

Comment: Just a word of caution, using window.open function will be blocked by a lot of browsers nowadays. It was exploited quite a bit. If it is just used locally it should not be a problem but something to keep in mind.

Comment: I tried adding this line to the function  if(window.location.href('url') {
  window.close();
  } but now the popup doesn't open anymore

Comment: don't call window.close try calling popupWindow.close() @neolith

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125648/close-popup-window

Comment: I have tried  if(popupWindow.location.href == 'url') {
  popupWindow.close();
  popupWindow.style.display = "none";
  }
  
 if(window.location.href == 'url') {
  window.close();
  window.style.display = "none";
 }
 
 if(popup.location.href == 'url') {
  popup.close();
  popup.style.display = "none";
 } None of the solutions work :(

Comment: try using self.close(); @neolith

Comment: self.close() closes the main window and not the popup. The problem is the if statement

Answer (score 0):

First get the url of the page you want to hide the popup

Use this for that  : `console.log(window.location.href)`

And then write the if condition with the address you get :

Example:

var popup = document.getElementById("xxx") -> Give the id of the popup window

```
if(window.location.href == "/yourspage"){
  popup .style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. What do I use for popupname? I tried "popupWindow", "window" and "popup"

Comment: The closing command is working, when I execute it outside the if statement, so the if statement must be wrong.

Comment: take the id of the popup using getElementByid and the store that to a variable and in place of popupname put the variable name , I have updated my answer